# Google Form dependent drop down list, using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need to create a google form with two questions that contain drop-down lists.  The first question is about a category, and the second one about a sub-category.

Is there a way to make the second question show only the options that belong to the category chosen in the first question using app script?

Comment: In a word "No",

Comment: Getting the real-time selection from the first drop-down question is not possible in Google Forms. Thus, it is not possible to programmatically make the second drop-down question with sub category based on the selection from the first question category.

Comment: You can create your simple web app via Google Apps Script. Just like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68478055/12968627

Answer (score 0):

If it don't have to use script for it, you can use the forms UI sections to achive this goal.

1. Add your dropdown question.
2. Add section for each option in the fitst question.
3. click the 3 dots on the first question and active the 'Go to section based on answer' option.

[Go to section based on answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8K1g.png)

After this, you will see a new menu next to each option in your question.
[Go to section...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv763.png)