# How to set the ability to go to section based on answer for Google Forms using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I already have the below code working, but can't seem to figure out how to set all but the last answer to "Go to next section" and the last answer to "Submit form".

```
function updateFormChoices() {
  try {
    // Spreadsheet info
    var spreadsheetId = "Spreadsheet ID here";
    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var columnBValues = getSpreadsheetValues(spreadsheetId, sheetName, "B");

    // Form info
    var formId = "Form ID here";
    var questionTitle = "Which of the following streams do you prefer over the other?";
    
    // Get the form
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

    // Get the question item
    var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
    
    // Find the question by title
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].getTitle() === questionTitle) {
        var item = items[i].asListItem();
        break;
      }
    }

    // Log information
    console.log("Column B Values: " + columnBValues.join(", "));
    
    // Update choices
    item.setChoiceValues(columnBValues);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}

function getSpreadsheetValues(spreadsheetId, sheetName, column) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getRange(column + "1:" + column + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  return values.flat().filter(String); // Flatten the array and remove empty values
}
```

I was using ChatGPT to come up with it as I really don't know much about this stuff, but it gave me the following code and I was hoping it would give me the go to section based on answer options, continuing to next section for all answers other than the last, and submitting form for the last.

```
    // Create choices with page navigation settings
    var choices = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < columnBValues.length; j++) {
      var choice = item.createChoice(columnBValues[j]);
      if (j < columnBValues.length - 1) {
        // Continue to next section for all choices except the last one
        choice.getPageNavigationItem().setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE);
      } else {
        // Submit form for the last choice
        choice.getPageNavigationItem().setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);
      }
      choices.push(choice);
    }

    // Set the choices
    item.setChoices(choices);
```

Comment: Can you confirm if what you'd like to do is similar to this feature? [Show questions based on answers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062).

Comment: @Saddles that's exactly what I want, but I don't want to have to do it manually every time the question updates using the script I have, but have the script do that, submitting for the last answer, and continuing to next section (the default option) for all the other answers (could be anywhere from 3 to 246 possible answers (not likely to be more than 27 but it's possible))

Comment: I was intrigued if it was possible to do what you'd like. After some testing and research, it seems that this can be considered a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new). This is supported by this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76481326) answered by [Samuel Lopez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21893919) stating the feature's unavailability through Google Apps Script.

Comment: @Saddles they said "there's no method available to Add a section in a Google Form as you need it" but that's not what I need, The section is set up, the default value is go to next section, I only need to make it to where the last answer submits the form via the "Show questions based on answers" feature you listed above. I can set it manually after each time the script is ran, but I'd like the script to set it for me instead like it's setting the answers.

Comment: also, I'm curious how I use the issue tracker you linked in that `feature request` link above (as in what the component and title categories are for?)

Comment: Apologies. Although you mentioned that the `code` you provided is `working`, it does not indicate that the `section` is already `set up`, which is why I've assumed that you'd like to create the section as well. Reading over the documentation available, there's no method for what you'd like to do. There is, however, a [setGoToPage(goToPageItem)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item#setgotopagegotopageitem) method, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: For the feature request link I provided, the `Component` is the service that you would like to report for a bug or request a new feature, while the `Title` is the name of what you'd like to submit.

Comment: @Saddles thanks for that link, I found a method to do what I want thanks to you, just did something the documents didn't directly show you can do but worked how I hoped it would, will post my answer right after this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do what I wanted, I used `item.setChoices(choices)` with choices being `item.createChoice(<choices directed from spreadsheet>, navigationType)` and navigationType being automatically set to `FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT` for the last one (the -1) and `FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE` for the rest.

```js
function updateFormChoices() {
  try {
    // Spreadsheet info
    var spreadsheetId = "<Your spreadsheet ID here>";
    var sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var columnBValues = getSpreadsheetValues(spreadsheetId, sheetName, "B");

    // Form info
    var formId = "<Your form ID here>";
    var questionTitle = "Which of the following streams do you prefer over the other?";
    
    // Get the form
    var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

    // Get the question item
    var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
    
    // Find the question by title
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i].getTitle() === questionTitle) {
        item = items[i].asListItem();
        break;
      }
    }

    // Create choices with navigation types
    var choices = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < columnBValues.length; j++) {
      var navigationType = j === columnBValues.length - 1 ?
        FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT :
        FormApp.PageNavigationType.CONTINUE;

      choices.push(item.createChoice(columnBValues[j], navigationType));
    }

    // Set choices
    item.setChoices(choices);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}

function getSpreadsheetValues(spreadsheetId, sheetName, column) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getRange(column + "1:" + column + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  return values.flat().filter(String); // Flatten the array and remove empty values
}
```